# How do I get the VersionName from this string?

Tags: bash

I have this string:

`package: name='my.package.name versionCode='221013140' versionName='00.00.05' platformBuildVersionName='12' platformBuildVersionCode='32' compileSdkVersion='32' compileSdkVersionCodename='12'`

Using bash, how can I get this value?

`00.00.05`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter expansion:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
string="package: name='my.package.name versionCode='221013140' versionName='00.00.05' platformBuildVersionName='12' platformBuildVersionCode='32' compileSdkVersion='32' compileSdkVersionCodename='12'"

version=${string#* versionName=\'}  # Remove everything up to the version name.
version=${version%%\'*}             # Remove everything after the first quote.

echo "$version"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bash` regex matching operator (`=~`):

```
[[ $string =~ versionName=\'([^\']*)\' ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```